# How can I read HDD volume serial number using VB 6?

Tags: vb6, ntfs, partition, serial-number, fat

How can I read HDD volume serial number using VB 6 but without using any ActiveX controls or third party add-ons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Private Declare Function GetVolumeInformation _
    Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetVolumeInformationA" _
    (ByVal lpRootPathName As String, _
    ByVal pVolumeNameBuffer As String, _
    ByVal nVolumeNameSize As Long, _
    lpVolumeSerialNumber As Long, _
    lpMaximumComponentLength As Long, _
    lpFileSystemFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpFileSystemNameBuffer As String, _
    ByVal nFileSystemNameSize As Long) As Long

Public Function GetSerialNumber( _
    ByVal sDrive As String) As Long

    If Len(sDrive) Then
        If InStr(sDrive, "\\") = 1 Then
            ' Make sure we end in backslash for UNC
            If Right$(sDrive, 1) <> "\" Then
                sDrive = sDrive & "\"
            End If
        Else
            ' If not UNC, take first letter as drive
            sDrive = Left$(sDrive, 1) & ":\"
        End If
    Else
        ' Else just use current drive
        sDrive = vbNullString
    End If

    ' Grab S/N -- Most params can be NULL
    Call GetVolumeInformation( _
        sDrive, vbNullString, 0, GetSerialNumber, _
        ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&, vbNullString, 0)
End Function
```

To call:

```
Dim Drive As String
Drive = InputBox("Enter drive for checking SN")
MsgBox Hex$(GetSerialNumber(Drive))
```

Source: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15908

Answer (score 1):

The following sample provides serial of the drive where your EXE is

```
'APi declaration
Declare Function GetVolumeInformation Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetVolumeInformationA" (ByVal lpRootPathName As String, ByVal lpVolumeNameBuffer As String, ByVal nVolumeNameSize As Long, lpVolumeSerialNumber As Long, lpMaximumComponentLength As Long, lpFileSystemFlags As Long, ByVal lpFileSystemNameBuffer As String, ByVal nFileSystemNameSize As Long) As Long

Sub subHDsn()
Dim TempAPi, VolumeSerial As Long
Dim strPATH As String

    On Error Resume Next

    TempAPi = 0
    VolumeSerial = 0
    If App.Path Like "*:*" Then
        'checking whether the drive is local or mapped
        strPATH = Left(App.Path, 3)
    Else
        'if it's a UNC
        strPATH = Left(App.Path, InStr((InStr(3, App.Path, "\") + 1), App.Path, "\"))
    End If
    'call API
    TempAPi = GetVolumeInformation(strPATH, VolumeName, 100, VolumeSerial, 100, FileSystemFlags, FileSystemName, 100)
    If TempAPi = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error calling API!", 16
        End
    End If
    'convert from HeX
    HDsn = Hex(VolumeSerial)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following sample without need API.

```
Public Function GetSerialNumber(ByVal sDrive As String) As String
   On Error Resume Next
   Open "Vol.bat" For Output As 1
      Print #1, "@vol %1%>DSN"
   Close
   Kill "DSN"
   Shell ("Vol.bat " + sDrive)
   Do
      Open "DSN" For Input As 1
      Input #1, GetSerialNumber
      Input #1, GetSerialNumber
      Close
   Loop While GetSerialNumber = ""
   GetSerialNumber = Right$(GetSerialNumber, 9)
   Kill "Vol.bat"
   Kill "DSN"
End Function
```